# Google Analytics Error in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-analytics, analytics

I am using Google Analytics on my website but get an error in Chrome that says:

```
GET http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
```

My code for embedding is this:

```
<script>
var gaProperty = 'UA-XXXX';
var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;
if (document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr + '=true') > -1) {
  window[disableStr] = true;
}
function gaOptout() {
  document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
  window[disableStr] = true;
}
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXX', 'website.com');
  ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Does anybody have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: That doesn't look like an error.

Comment: Hmm, but Chrome shows it in the error category...

Comment: on Google Analytics itself? Not when you visit the page that has this code on it?

Comment: I've put that code on my website to integrate Analytics. And I get that error when I visit my website with the code on it...

Answer (score 0):

i implemented GA code in my WordPress blog yesterday and i got the same error. I googled for a long time i wasn't be able to solve the issue.

However, I finally implemented the code just before the end of HEAD label http://screencast.com/t/Bh5L9x3Nk8
I do nothing and now (a few hours later) GA seems work fine and its real time tool is registering activity http://screencast.com/t/lI1eJzduJ7iR

Cheers,
Jose